# Displaying wrong time difference

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I tried many ways to display the difference between two times, but I am unable to find a solution:

```
long strt = System.currentTimeMillis();//1462968291733
Thread.sleep(5000);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();//1462968296733

long diff = end - strt;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(diff);
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");
calendar.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

System.out.println(calendar.getTime());//05:30:05
```

It is printing wrong output:

> Thu Jan 01 05:30:05 IST 1970

The output should be

> Thu Jan 01 00:00:05 IST 1970

Comment: i copy / paste your code its working fine in my env.

Comment: "_Actual output is_" Do you mean "_Actual output **should be**_"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting confuse with the time zone. Try the following:

```
long strt = System.currentTimeMillis();// 1462968291733
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();// 1462968296733

    long diff = end - strt;


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(diff);
    TimeZone cutsomTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");

     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat
                ("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    formatter.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));//

    formatter.setTimeZone(cutsomTimeZone);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

First, as the javadoc says, `System.currentMillis()` return the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 in **UTC** which is obviously different from IST.

Second, the `Date` object return by `calendar.getTime()` does not bear a timezone. The output you get with `System.out.println(calendar.getTime())` use the default `TimeZone` of your system which seems to be IST.

Third, please don't use the `Date` api, it is really bad. When possible, prefer the `java.time` one.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the default print out uses the default locale, which is `+5:30` in your case.

You'll need to format the output in the time zone you want, e.g. by using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by dejvuth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37162786/642706) and the [answer by orris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37162852/642706) are both correct.

**Avoid the old date-time classes**. They have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. For Java 6 & 7, much of the functionality has been back-ported by the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android by the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

No need for time zones at all to capture elapsed time.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). In Java 8 the current moment is captured up to a resolution of only [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), but a new implementation of [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) in Java 9 will capture up to nanoseconds depending on your computer’s clock hardware capability.

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
…
Instant stop = Instant.now();
```

A [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) captures a span of time as a total number of whole seconds and a fraction of a second as nanoseconds. This value is not attached to the timeline.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

The java.time classes use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard when generating a textual representation of a date-time value. For a duration of two and a half seconds, you will get a value like `PT2.5S` where the `P` marks the beginning (for Period), and the `T` separates any years-month-days from hours-minutes-seconds. This format prevents the ambiguity of the clock-format where `00:00:02.5` looks like a time-of-day of two minutes past midnight. But if you so desire you can interrogate the `Duration` for the numbers.

```
String output = duration.toString();
```